# std::list iterator.erase() is causing an invalid pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

Hi I'm having a problem with `std::list` where I'm getting a `free()`: invalid pointer error when I call the erase function, and then iterate up to that element. I was hoping it would skip over that element since it was deleted... My first assumption was maybe you need a new iterator because the previous one is stale. So my solution was to set my iterator to `list.begin()` and then advance it. This is still causing an error though.

What I'm trying to do is set an element in the list to an element that is n spaces ahead. Then delete the element that is n spaces ahead.

```
#include "roulette.h"
#include <iostream>

uint roulette(uint people, uint step)
{
    std::list<uint>::iterator iterator;
    uint position = 0;

    for(uint i = people; i > 0; i--)
        gl_myList.push_front(i);

    iterator = gl_myList.begin();
    while(people > 1)
    {
        for(uint i = 0; i < step - 1; i++)
        {
            position++;
            iterator++;
            if(iterator == gl_myList.end())
            {
                iterator = gl_myList.begin();
                position = 0;
            }
        }
        *iterator = kill(iterator, step);

        /*
         * This was my attempt to fix it
        iterator = gl_myList.begin();
        advance(iterator, position);
        */

        people--;
    }

    return *iterator;
}

#include "roulette.h"
#include <iostream>
uint kill(std::list<uint>::iterator iterator, uint step)
{
    uint value;
    for(uint i = 0; i < step; i++)
    {
        iterator++;
        if(iterator == gl_myList.end())
            iterator = gl_myList.begin();
    }
    value = *iterator;
    gl_myList.erase(iterator);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: What if `gl_myList.begin() == gl_myList.end()` is true? Then you're dereferencing an invalid iterator.

Comment: The code for kill is at the bottom.

Comment: @user1932934 you should set the value first and then kill it. that way you can return the iterator and fix the invalidated iterator problem by assigning it to the one in the loop. EDIT: Also why the first loop conditions is `i < step-1` while the second one is `i < step`? Is it a typo or is it how its supposed to be?

Comment: I have the conditions different because the problem involves counting from different positions. Either starting at your position or the person next to you. If it's the person next to you then you would be taking step - 1 steps. (You are already starting at them)

I'll try what you and Mark Ransom suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
std::list<uint>::iterator advanceList(std::list<uint>::iterator start, int step) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < step; i++) {
        start++;
        if(start == gl_myList.end())
            start = gl_myList.begin();
    }
    return start;
}
```

And in your main code:

```
while(people > 1) {
    iterator = advanceList(iterator, step);
    auto tmpIterator = advanceList(iterator, step-1);
    *iterator = *tmpIterator;
    iterator = gl_myList.erase(tmpIterator);

    people--;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When your `kill` function returns, you're trying to assign the return value to `*iterator` - but you invalidated the iterator in `kill`!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "invalidated" the iterator? Iterators are new to me.

Comment: I don't know the internal of `std::iterator` but I think it doesn't matter. Since there is no element in your list, both will be equal to `gl_myList.end()`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I fill it, that's what push_front does right?

Comment: @user1932934 when you call `erase` on an iterator you invalidate it, because the iterator isn't pointing to an element of the container anymore. You aren't allowed to perform *any* operations on an invalid iterator.

Comment: @MarkRansom so if you have two iterators, do both of them get invalidated?

Comment: This sort of goes along with what Gasim just said. So if I make a copy of an iterator, and invalidate one it invalidates the other?

Comment: The function `kill` invalidates the iterator if and only if `step` is a multiple of the length of the list.

Comment: At best it is equals to `list.end()`. Worst case is that it literally point to nothing and cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @Gasim yes both iterators get invalidated. After all neither of them knows whether it's a copy or the original.